# Async and Await on NodeJS continues loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

I have a Lambda script that I'm trying to run hourly. It has a list of URLs in a file and hits the Pagespeed Insights API for each URL. The issue is, it runs multiple times for each URL and saves them to the Dynamo DB. I'm not familiar with how async/await work completely and feel like that might be my issue. It's possible it received an error back and the script tries again?

**My code:**

```
var id;

const insertRecords = async (_id, _url, _lighthouseResults) => {

const metrics = _lighthouseResults.lighthouseResult.audits.metrics.details.items[0];

console.log(metrics);
    const params = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Item: { id: _id,
                created_at: new Date().toISOString(),
                URL: _url,
                metrics
            },
    };
    console.log("got to db entry")
    console.log(_id)
    console.log(_url)
    console.log(_lighthouseResults)

    return docClient.put(params).promise(); // convert to Promise
}

exports.putItemHandler = async (event) => { // Async function
  for (const url of urls) {
    id = v4();
    console.log(url + " - " + id);

    const lighthouseResults = await getLighthouse(url);     

    await insertRecords(id, url, lighthouseResults) // wait until it finish and go to next item
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        // throw error; don't care about this error, just continue
      });
  }
  console.log("Done");
};

const getLighthouse = async (url) => {
    console.log("inside getLighthouse")

    try {
        const resp = await axios.get(endpoint, {
            params: {
                key: API_KEY,
                url: url,
                category: 'performance',
                strategy: 'mobile'
            }
        });

        return resp.data

    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }

}
```

Comment: "*it runs multiple times for each URL*" - are you sure that the array doesn't contain duplicates? What do your `console.log` statements output?

Comment: it pulls from URLs.json which looks like [ “url”, “url”, “url” ]

Comment: "*It's possible it received an error back and the script tries again?*" - yes, that's possible. Please do some debugging, like checking how often `putItemHandler` is called. What do the logs say? Please share your findings, we can hardly help you otherwise. There are no obvious problems in the async/await usage of your code.

Comment: I’m running it by clicking Test on the lambda function. It outputs all items to log as specified but times out after 10 min. Would the lambda timeout cause it to continuously try again?

Comment: I don't think it would do that. Are the logs telling you that it got called again right after the timeout?